# Where can I ask about the definitions of automotive terminology?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have [asked the following on Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/87924/39667), however, it has been closed as *off-topic*. Where can I find the answer?

> Some companies sell their vehicles as "hybrid" vehicles, in that they
> take both an electric plug and fossil fuels to make them go. Some are
> referred to as "Self Charging Hybrids", as they do not have an
> external electrical connection to charge the battery.
>
> Other companies sell their vehicles as "Electric Vehicles" with a
> "Diesel Range Extender". These take an external electrical connection
> to charge the battery, as well as diesel to fuel the range extender.
>
> For example, when I was looking to purchase a fully electric vehicle
> recently, the salesperson for one manufacturer literally said to me,
> verbatim, that their vehicle "is not a hybrid, it's an EV with a range
> extender."
>
> To the layperson, these could arguably seem like the same thing, as
> ultimately the "Diesel Range Extender" is, in reality, an Internal
> Combustion Engine. What is the legal definition that separates these
> two classifications? Is there a good reason for this, or is it just
> marketing shenanigans?
>
> Does the law constrain the way that auto manufacturers can
> characterize their vehicles and, if so, how?
>
> (Specific company names excluded to mitigate the risk of slander.)

This is not an engineering question as I, as do most, understand the difference between an *internal combustion engine* and a *battery*. It is also not a sustainability question as, again, there is little argument that fossil fuels are generally bad. As this surrounds the legal definitions of things, I thought "law" was the best place but evidently, I was mistaken. Where should I go?

Comment: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com seems a potential fit - but (slightly ironically) - it might be worth checking their scope and meta first

Comment: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/45193/would-the-gm-extended-range-electric-voltec-system-be-practical-in-a-truck-or-su seems vaguely relevant as well

Comment: From [the comment thread](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141904/discussion-on-question-by-james-geddes-when-does-a-range-extender-become-a-hy) (now moved to chat. My emphasis): *'The EPA regulations explicitly define the terms "hybrid engine or powertrain", "hybrid vehicle", and "electric vehicle". I have* ***voted to reopen.*** *And California's Air Resources Board defines "range-extended battery-electric vehicle".'*

Comment: Thanks! The question was reopened on law.